# How to specify a pre-release package dependency in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

How do you configure Xcode (13.2) to add a dependency on a pre-release version of a package?

For example, right now [Sparkle](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle) has a `2.1.0-beta.2` release which I would like to test in my app.

More accurately stated, I would like to accept `2.1.0-beta.x` up to and including the full release of `2.1.0` and I'd like Xcode's "Update to latest package versions" to find the new releases for me without me changing anything in the configuration (eg like you can do with npm).

I can't find any obvious way to achieve this using the Xcode UI. If indeed you can't, is there a way to specify this version range by editing a config directly?

[image]

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/179#issuecomment-193061114), `2.1.0-beta.2` < `2.1.0`, which is why I have tried `2.0.0` in the screenshot.